# Export a file as .ai (adobe illustrator)

Tags: python, computer-vision, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm building an application in python thats going to create images that need to be exported to adobe illustrator. I was wondering if anyone has ever worked with AI and has written code that exports files in the .ai file format?

****Update
The user will be editing paths exported from our application and imported to AI. So if there is another way to do so like maybe SVG, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: There are PDF libraries that let you create PDF graphics from Python. Illustrator opens and edits PDF files, so maybe that would be easier?

Comment: I should have put this in the question sorry. The most important thing I need the user to be able to edit is paths. So the export will be of line paths that the user will manipulate on AI.

Comment: PDF documents can contain not only text but also lines, arcs, and Bezier curves. Which are editable in Illustrator. Have a look at the Python libraryfrom www.reportlab.com